# Why is the complementary function $y_c$ of $y'' +y=\sin^3 x$ ... $y_c=A\cos x +B\sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From Morris's' Differential equations Book PG 226

[image]

From where did he find the complementary function of (a)?
In the book he only described how to find complementary functions from finding the roots of the characteristic equation. He described how to find the complementary function when
1- The roots are Real and distinct
2- The roots are Real but multiple/repeated
3- The roots are complex
4- Complex and repeated. etc.
$m^2 + m =0$ gives real roots: $m=1, m=0$. That results in the complementary function
$$y_c= c_1e^x+c_2$$
From where did he get the sines and cosines? The only way I know of getting those is if the roots are complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formula $e^{ix}=\cos x +i \sin x$ You made a mistake it's $m^2+1=0$ not $m^2+m=0$. The differential equation is:
$$y'' +y=\sin^3 x$$
Nit:
$$y'' +y'=\sin^3 x$$

Comment: Ah i see, such a simple mistake. Sorry for that hahaha

Comment: You're welcome @AbdulmalekAlem